# Match 2 differents object with the same instance name

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know if it is possible to match object with their **instance name**.

I got :

```
class AnimatedEntity : DrawableEntity
{
    Animation BL { get; set; }
    Animation BR { get; set; }
    Animation TL { get; set; }
    Animation TR { get; set; }
    Animation T { get; set; }
    Animation R { get; set; }
    Animation L { get; set; }
    Animation B { get; set; }

    Orientation orientation ;

    public virtual int Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //draw depends on orientation
    }
}
```

and

```
enum Orientation { 
    SE, SO, NE, NO, 
    N , E, O, S, 
    BL, BR, TL, TR, 
    T, R, L, B 
}
```

Where Orientation is an Enum and Animation a class.

Can I call the correct Animation from the Orientation with the same name ?

Comment: Is it possible to inject the `Animation` into the `Orientation` object?

Comment: No Animation depend on a Entity instance, Orientation depend on the scene

Comment: I find this may be : typeof(MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName, but it's just half of the way

Comment: sounds like you need to use reflection on this like `objectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("R").GetValue()`

Comment: It isn't really clear what you want to do? If you want to map the objects to each other, you could use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map Animation to Orientation, and then convert one to the other as required.

Comment: Is it a good libs because there wiki is on Tatooine : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Any method you find to do this will not be as good as redesigning your code so you don't have to.

Comment: @CyrilALFARO yes Automapper is very solid. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started is a good place to start

Comment: I precise that Orientation is a Enum and Animation a class

Comment: How about seal them into interface, them let your instance compare them to one another? Note: you must override the `.Equals` and `.GetHasCode` method if you're on it.

Comment: You can't call *anything* from an enum. Can you explain where you are calling the Animation from?

Comment: @Kendall Frey I edit question

Comment: Animation is simply a list of coords on a texture and delay between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing the Animations in properties, how about using a dictionary?

```
Dictionary<Orientation, Animation> anim = new Dictionary<Orientation, Animation> {
    { Orientation.BL, blAnimation },
    { Orientation.BR, brAnimation },
    { Orientation.TL, tlAnimation },
    { Orientation.TR, trAnimation },
    { Orientation.T, tAnimation },
    { Orientation.R, rAnimation },
    { Orientation.L, lAnimation },
    { Orientation.B, bAnimation }
};
```

You can then use `anim[orientation]` to access the appropriate animation.

Comment: How I did't think about that... 2:00am... ok I go to bed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a `Dictionary` would be a good option. It could even have an `Animation` index if the animations would be set from outside:

```
class AnimatedEntity : DrawableEntity
{
    Dictionary<Orientation, Animation> Animations { get; set; }

    public AnimatedEntity()
    {
        Animations = new Dictionary<Orientation, Animation>();
    }

    public Animation this[Orientation orientation] 
    { 
        get{ return Animations[orientation]; }
        set{ Animations[orientation] = value;}
    }

    Orientation Orientation { get; set; }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Animation anim = Animations[Orientation];
    }
}
```

Would be used like:

```
AnimatedEntity entity = new AnimatedEntity();
entity[Orientation.B] = bAnimation;
entity[Orientation.E] = eAnimation;
entity[Orientation.SE] = seAnimation;
```

Comment: Indeed index have a better syntax than `public void addAnimation(Orientation or, Animation an) { anims.Add(or, an); }`. Thank for the additional information.